# How to remove the quotes around JSON.stringify() output for a String

Tags: javascript, json

I'm reading a huge file of numbers, and, for "efficiency", collecting the results in a String that looks like a 2D array, not an actual array.  But, I want to generate JSON where the value looks like an array, not a String.

As a highly simplified example, if the object were

```
var foo = {
       realArray: [1,2,3,4,5],
       fakeArray: '[1,2,3,4,5]'    // String pretending to be an array
    }
```

I want the JSON output for the two fields to be identical, so that some later program  parsing the generated json will "see" an array, not a string.

```
{
   realArray: [1,2,3,4,5],
   fakeArray: [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

My googling and prelim tests have failed.  [In this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-gson/dJT5wR_3UA0) he's trying to create illegal JSON.  And he's using Java/GSON.  I'm creating, I think, "legal" JSON.

As a test I tried overriding `toJSON()` as follows to remove the leading ", but when you call JSON.stringify(foo) it removes the leading [ and keeps the quote!

```
foo.toJSON = function() {
    return {
        realArray: this.realArray,
        fakeArray: this.fakeArray.substring(1)
    };
};
```

yields

```
{
   "realArray":[1,2,3,4,5],
   "fakeArray":"1,2,3,4,5]"    <<< removed the [, not the "
}
```

Currently I can do it in a very brute force fashion, concatenating a bunch of smaller JSON.stringifies of each field in the foo into a huge long String, but it's tedious because the real foo object has a bunch of objects.  Is there a cleaner alternative?

Comment: Then you need to serialize an array rather than a string.

Comment: You need to learn to distinct between _syntax_ and actual objects. Your string value stays a string value of course – it doesn’t magically become an array just because you remove the first character …

Comment: @CBroe I know that, of course it remains a string on my side.  What I want is for somebody parsing the generated json file to get the array, not a string.  Will edit question.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
foo.toJSON = function() {
    return {
        realArray: this.realArray,
        fakeArray: eval(this.fakeArray)
    };
};
```

This might eat up any efficiencies you've achieved though...